# Reenable to add me to a private Facebook group

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

I left a private Facebook group years ago with the option to prevent me from adding again to it. Now I would like to reenter that group but I can't and they can't add me again.

How can I lift this restriction?

I checked the Blocking section in the FB settings, but I can't find anything related to this.